# Why does my Maven build of Eclipse (Galileo) fail?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3, eclipse-3.5

I am trying to build Galileo with Maven on Windows 10. The build being done at the DOS prompt not within Eclipse. The plugin requires org.mozilla.rhino but it fails download. Builds of all other versions Helios-Mars build perfectly ok
In my parent pom I have the following profile:-

```
    <profile>
        <id>galileo</id>
        <properties>
            <target-eclipse-repo>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/</target-eclipse-repo>
            <!--http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/-->
            <platform-feature>com.ipl.products.eclipse.cantpp.platform.galileofeature</platform-feature>
            <platform-plugin>com.ipl.products.eclipse.cantpp.platform.galileo</platform-plugin>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>platform/Galileo</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
```

The Error I get is:-

```
[INFO] Fetching org.mozilla.rhino_1.7.1.v20090521.jar.pack.gz from http://ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/eclipse/releases/galileo/200909241140/aggregate/plugins/ (0B of 314.84kB at 0B/s)
[ERROR] An error occurred while transferring artifact packed: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.rhino,1.7.1.v20090521 from repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/200909241140/aggregate:
[ERROR]    Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.rhino,1.7.1.v20090521.:
[ERROR]       File has invalid content:C:\Temp\signatureFile8640129394392843080.jar:
[ERROR]          Invalid content:lib/js.jar
[ERROR] Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider$MirroringFailedException: Could not mirror artifact osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.rhino,1.7.1.v20090521 into the local Maven repository.See log output for details. The file "lib/js.jar" in the jar "C:\Temp\signatureFile8640129394392843080.jar" has been tampered! -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider$MirroringFailedException: Could not mirror artifact osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.rhino,1.7.1.v20090521 into the local Maven repository.See log output for details.
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
```

I tried adding rhino to my local repository but Maven still tries to download org.mozilla.rhino

Using Java 7.21. Maven 3.3.9

I have trying to get this to build for 2 days so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your local maven repo then retrying?

Comment: Yes tried I deleted everything including cache from my local repository but it did not fix it